# Custom QGraphicsItemGroup for event handling

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, graphics

I have program where the user selects a block and can move it around the screen; however, the blocks that are inside the region of the main block need to move in relation to the main block's motion.

I accomplished this by making a QGraphicsItemGroup of these blocks and setting the right flags.

```
    dragGroup = this->scene()->createItemGroup(items);
    this->dragGroup->setHandlesChildEvents(true);
    this->dragGroup->setFlag(ItemIsMovable);
```

This, consequently, ignores the main items mouseReleaseEvent() where the group is dismantled. Therefore, the blocks inside the main block are stuck in the group and cannot be moved independently after the initial drag is complete. My idea is to make a custom QGraphicsItemGroup where its mouseReleaseEvent() calls the main blocks event to kill the group.

I cannot figure out how to do this. I have tried sub classing it but the scene creates the base class and not my derived class, and a dynamic_cast didn't seem to work in this case.

OR, is there another way of accomplishing the same thing, having QGraphicsItemGroup control some events and the blocks themselves control other? Or is a QGraphicsItemGroup not the right fit in this situation.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely follow what you're trying to accomplish (an image would help here), but it sounds like the QGraphicsItem function of installSceneEventFilter may be what you're looking for, rather than deriving from QGraphicsItemGroup: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#installSceneEventFilter

Comment: As in I filter the drop event from the group to the main item?

Comment: Yes, install the event filter on members when they're added to the group and remove it when the leave.